# Using Bootstrap 3.x, how does one correctly shift a container div to the left (instead of centered)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started playing with Bootstrap (wow do I regret starting so late!), and I'm trying to learn how to do things by its conventions.  I realize there are several ways I could "hack" a `container` to the left, but what's the proper way to place it on the left instead of centered (how should I do it by Bootstrap's methodology)?  I can't imagine every designer wants their webpage centered?

**Please note:** I am *not* referring to a fluid page (consuming the whole page with the content).  My desire is to simply leave all the "gutter" space on the right side, rather than divided evenly between the left and right.

---

Incase I'm being unclear:

Currently:

`XXXXXXX[<div class="container">]XXXXXXX`

Goal:

`[<div class="container">]XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: Just change margin-right and margin-left on .container to be zero. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a special `container-left` class and only apply it as needed to extend the `container` class. For example, if you're nesting containers you may want some to remain centered.

```
.container-left {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Demo on Bootply: http://bootply.com/107716

Comment: That was approximately what I was thinking... and certainly seems the cleanest.  Does bootstrap simply not have anything built in?  It just seems so odd that the assumption is that everything should be centered that I assumed there was a built in way I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class="pull-left" to it. 
This class will make sure the element floats to the left.

```
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
```

OR

You could just remove that class as it seems to do little more than centre the div. As you can see below the container only centres it and adds a bit of padding.

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Functionally that would do the trick... but I could just as easily drop the left margin auto property to a fixed value if I wanted to do something "hacky."  What I'm wondering is what the correct approach would be if I wanted to follow bootstrap's methodology?

Comment: Re your edit: it also does quite a bit with sizes, based on the size of the screen, which is quite valuable in combination with their grid system

Comment: Looking through the css it doesnt look like changing the margin left to fixed would have much of a knock on effect. Just try it and see what it looks like. Try testing in different size browsers to make sure the media queriers are still working?